# Aptana Studio 3 - Eclipse plugin installation error

Tags: eclipse-plugin, aptana3

I am trying to install Aptana Studio 3 in my Eclipse Helios.

I getting the following message

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:
(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).

Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,beaver,3.0.0.1309394487.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: b88d46ab944b899ff869f6bbbcb8e878 and found 7236dbb8536eed3c7bc44c0062d866aa.

Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.aptana.editor.beaver,3.0.0.1318454741.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: f5ab07e7033d77680043d511a72f0f00 and found 5164259b4a7679c76e7ff9ec4f0d9cbb.
```

Unable to find a suitable answer. Any help appreciated.